# Qemu SPARC boot panic on Solaris

Tags: solaris, qemu, boot, kvm, sparc

I want to boot Solaris8 SPARC version by Qemu.

```
$ qemu-system-sparc64 -boot d -cdrom SOL_8_204_SPARC.iso -net nic -net user -m 2048
```

But it shows this error:

```
OpenBIOS for Sparc64
Configuration device id QEMU version 1 machine id 0
kernel cmdline 
CPUs: 1 x SUNW,UltraSPARC-IIi
UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 built on Oct 28 2019 17:08
  Type 'help' for detailed information
Trying cdrom:f...
Not a bootable ELF image
Not a bootable a.out image

Loading FCode image...
Loaded 5936 bytes
entry point is 0x4000
Evaluating FCode...
open isn't unique.
Alloc of 0x2000 bytes at 0x16000 refused.

panic[cpu0]/thread=10408000: BOP_ALLOC failed

0000000010406ea0 unix:boot_alloc+44 (2000, 2000, 1000, 30000016000, 31002afd100, 30000014000)
  %l0-3: 000000001041b2d0 0000030ffffff138 0000000000000001 000000001044bdc0
  %l4-7: 000000001044af18 000000001044aef8 000000001044bd20 000000000000000b
0000000010406f50 unix:segkmem_alloc+30 (30000016000, 2000, 0, 0, 1044efe0, 1044b300)
  %l0-3: 0000030ffffff5c0 ffffffffffffe000 0000000000000000 000000001044bdc0
  %l4-7: 000000001044af18 000000001044aef8 000000001044f840 000000001004a438
0000000010407010 genunix:vmem_xalloc+3e4 (1044ea18, 1044ee20, ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, 0, 0)
  %l0-3: 000000001004a3b4 ffffffffffffe000 000000001044ea18 0000000000002000
  %l4-7: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 000000001044ea38
0000000010407140 genunix:kmem_slab_create+8c (0, 0, 2000, 300000043c0, 0, 1044ea18)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000000 0000030ffffff220 0000000000000000 000000001044bdc0
  %l4-7: 000000001044af18 00000300000043c0 000000001044f840 0000000000007fa3
0000000010407230 genunix:kmem_cache_alloc+180 (0, 0, 0, 300000043c0, 0, 0)
  %l0-3: 0000030000004740 ffffffffffffe000 000000001044ea18 0000000000002000
  %l4-7: 0000030ffffff220 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 000000001044ea38
00000000104072e0 genunix:kmem_slab_create+130 (200, 30000014000, 2000, 3000000da40, 0, 200)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000000 ffffffffffffe000 000000001044ea18 0000000000002000
  %l4-7: 0000030fffffef68 000003000000da40 0000000000002000 000000001044ea38
00000000104073d0 genunix:kmem_cache_alloc+180 (0, 0, 0, 3000000da40, 0, 0)
  %l0-3: 000003000000ddc0 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 ffffffffffffffff
  %l4-7: 0000030000013fc8 00000300000052c0 0000030000013fc8 0000030000013fc0
0000000010407480 genunix:kmem_alloc+2c (2000, 0, 2000, 3000000da40, 0, 30000013fb8)
  %l0-3: 0000030000005640 0000000010147bfa 0000000000000000 0000000000000020
  %l4-7: 0000000010446678 0000000010452543 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0000000010407530 krtld:kobj_zalloc+c (2000, 1000, 2000, 300000052c0, f0, 0)
  %l0-3: 000003000000e740 ffffffffffffffc0 000000001044f8e0 00000000000003c0
  %l4-7: 000000001044aa70 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 000000000000000b
00000000104075e0 krtld:kobj_open_file+38 (2000, 30000011f88, 104397f0, 0, 0, 1)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000008 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
  %l4-7: 0000000000000008 000000001004a3b4 0000000010452538 000000001004a438
0000000010407690 genunix:mod_read_system_file+70 (10437c00, 2000, 1, 0, 26, 1043a0d8)
  %l0-3: 0000000000004000 0000000000000008 0000000000004008 0000000000000000
  %l4-7: 0000000000002000 000000001004a3b4 0000000010451670 000000001004a438
00000000104077b0 genunix:kmem_init+1b8 (10471b50, 0, 0, 91, 1, 291)
  %l0-3: 000000001041dc00 0000000000002000 000000001004a3b4 000000001004a438
  %l4-7: 0000000010418590 0000000000001fff 000000001040d970 0000000000007fa3
0000000010407880 unix:startup_memlist+b14 (10418400, 30000016080, 30000000000, 10418668, 2000, 30000016000)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000103 0000000010423c00 0000000000000020 0000031002c00000
  %l4-7: 0000000010418400 000000001041d000 000000001041c000 000000001041b000
0000000010407970 unix:startup+c (10428c00, 0, 0, 1, 0, ffffffffffffffff)
  %l0-3: 0000000010026090 000000000000d925 0000000000000afd 0000000000000000
  %l4-7: 0000000010472880 00000000002e8c43 00000000000beafd 0000000000000afd
0000000010407a20 genunix:main+4 (1040d400, 2000, 10407ec0, 10408030, fff2, 10052a0c)
  %l0-3: 0000000010408000 0000000000000001 0000000000000015 0000000000000f36
  %l4-7: 0000000010429618 0000000010472880 00000000000d7438 0000000000000540

skipping system dump - no dump device configured
rebooting...
BOOTpanic - kernel: prom_reboot: reboot call returned!
EXIT
```

While it works on 32bit execution by `qemu-system-sparc`.

My Qemu version: 5.0.0-8

Comment: Can you boot the 32-bit kernel under `qemu-system-sparc64`?  I'm not sure how to do that offhand under QEMU, but it should be possible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the ISO file I have is the SPARC version. I can boot 32bit by `qemu` or Wmware. But if I boot the SPARC file by `qemu-system-sparc` it will boot `32bit` version which could boot well. But the only 64bit can't.

Comment: Just to be sure, I meant using `qemu-system-sparc64` to boot the ***32-bit*** kernel.  You should be able to boot a 32-bit Solaris 8 kernel on 64-bit SPARC "hardware".  You'll have to dig through the QEMU and Solaris documentation to figure out how to do that, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I checked the 32-bit version with `qemu-system-sparc64` it didn't show any error but it froze at the beginning and nothing loaded.